# Is there a good way to update a TextView when an EditText view is deselected?

Tags: android

I'd like to have a TextView be updated to show what a user has entered in an EditText view in Android.

Is there a way to do this when the EditText view is deselected?

(I know how to change the TextView to display the text entered in EditText, but I can't find out how to tell when EditText is deselected, if there is a way. Perhaps deselected is the wrong word? When the user has stopped typing and hit enter, at least.)

Comment: Perhaps, something like assigning the edittext value to a string and then passing it to the textview can help?!! I'm not really sure about this and this is just a wild guess. That's why commenting rather than answering. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I got this part - it was knowing when to pass the value from EditText somewhere else that I needed to find :) Thanks though!

Comment: Cool.. All the best for the development.. :)

Comment: Thanks :) Both the answers were very helpful, so I'm now tackling newer, more exciting bugs ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 edtSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
tvhello.setText(s.toString());
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: in afterTextChanged() you can set the text for a textview.

Answer (score 2):

You can check when the edit text looses its focus by adding an OnFocusChangedListener to your edit text: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html . So your code will be something like this:

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
                        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus) {
                    String text = editText.getText().toString();
                    textView.setText(text);
                }
                            }       });
```